# Egopay payment gateway api callback url not getting response

Tags: php, payment, gateway

I am getting this message **"This param is required - 'product_id'"** in callback success url.

```
<?php
require('EgoPaySci.php');
try {
    $oEgopay = new EgoPaySci(array(
        'store_id'          => 'STORE ID',
        'store_password'    => 'STORE PASSWORD'
    ));
    $sPaymentHash = $oEgopay->createHash(array(
        'amount'    => '3.00',
        'currency'  => 'USD',
        'description' => 'My payment',
        'cf_1' => 'My custom data'
    ));
} catch (EgoPayException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo EgoPaySci::EGOPAY_PAYMENT_URL; ?>" method="post">    
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $sPaymentHash ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Payment" />
</form>
```

For detail please check this https://www.egopay.com/developers.html

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Is there any sandbox mode option in egopay? How can I test the process in testing mode? have you developed in wordpress? Thanks.